# Combine audio and webm in pure js

Tags: javascript, html5-video, html5-audio, data-conversion, webm

Audio can be generated, modified, analyzed with the audioContext supported by all modern browsers. In Google Chrome it's even possible to generate a webm video file from canvas animations.

But is there any possibility to combine audio and a webm video in the browser using javascript and no further server side dependencies? I thought about something like [crunker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crunker) but with audio+video instead of audio+audio.

I spend hours on searching but didn't find anything so far. Any tip / hint or idea is welcome.

Comment: This is possible.  You can use MediaRecorder, but I'm curious... do you have the requirement of not re-encoding the video?  You could mux the old video stream into the new file, but this isn't efficient and is a lot of work.  To my knowledge, there isn't anything that does this off-the-shelf today, reliably or efficiently.  Some folks have ported FFmpeg to run in web assembly, but that's about it.

Comment: But does MediaStream allow for offline processing? As far as I understand, it only records what is played in real time. But If I already have the generated webm video file and the audio file separately, the combination should take a couple of seconds but not as long as the audio or video file is.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately MediaRecorder will only run in realtime.  So, you'll need something like the FFmpeg.js example.

Comment: There is a Web Codecs standard currently being worked on, but it isn't really available yet.

Comment: bummer, the strugggle I have with FFmpeg in general and I think it translates to the js version, is that they use licenced algorithms and I can't really figure out if its ok to use them or not especially in commercial projects. Thx for your help so far! Do you have any reference to that new codec so I can keep an eye on it?

Comment: Web Codecs:  https://github.com/WICG/web-codecs

Comment: If it's worth the effort to you, WebM is just Matroska, which is just a schema for EBML, which is a standardized format.  You may be able to find existing libraries for just WebM/Matroska that you can use.  In the past, I've written my own muxer... but I didn't need to combine streams like you do, which requires a more full featured muxer.

Answer (score 0):

There's this https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/ffmpeg/merging-wav-and-webm-into-mp4.html

A web assembly version of ffmpeg that is used to join the WebM and Wav into an MP4.

https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC

https://github.com/muaz-khan/Ffmpeg.js